# Adding current menu item class to wordpress menu template

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function, wp-nav-walker

So i've been trying to use my own menu templates for using things like bootstrap within the menu items for scaling. Untill now it works incredibly well but i stumbled upon a problem.

By adding and deleting some classes i, in my mistake, deleted some standard classes like the `.current-menu-item class` for the active menu-item styling. I've been trying out some of the answers on google and Stack but sadly couldn't find a good solution. So this is what i have right now:

```php
/**
 * Class walker_home_menu
 * Menu for the home page
 */
class walker_home_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{

    // Displays start of an element. E.g '<li> Item Name'
    // @see Walker::start_el()
    // In your functions.php

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent\n";
    }

    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent\n";
    }

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0)
    {
        $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array)$item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';
        $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args);
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';
        $output .= $indent . '';
        $attributes = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->target) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->xfn) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->url) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';
        $item_output = '<li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 home-menu-item text-center">';
        $item_output .= $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $item_output .= "</li>";
        $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $output .= "\n";
    }
}
```

The goal i would like to achieve is to add an `active` class for active menu-items so that i'm able to give the active menu-item a different background-color throught `CSS`.

Thanks for the help in advance!
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution to my question. Since i think many will create, or like to create custom menu's i'm answering my own question.

Before posting my code i've tried to add the variable `$class_items` to the `<li class="..">` section. But i didn't have any succes. Atleast untill now.

So the answer is to add the wordpress menu item classes the correct way. See the code below.

```php
        $item_output = '<li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 home-menu-item text-center' . $class_names . '">';
```

The wordpress class names like `.current-menu-item` for `.active` styling will be added after the new created lay-out i've made myself.

Hope this helps everyone having this issue.

Simple solution for those who would like to copy my code as a base, Here is the final working snippet.

```php
/**
 * Class walker_home_menu
 * Menu for the home page
 */
class walker_home_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{

    // Displays start of an element. E.g '<li> Item Name'
    // @see Walker::start_el()
    // In your functions.php

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent\n";
    }

    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent\n";
    }

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0)
    {
        $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array)$item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' ' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';
        $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args);
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';
        $output .= $indent . '';
        $attributes = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->target) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->xfn) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->url) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';
        $item_output = '<li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 home-menu-item text-center' . $class_names . '">';
        $item_output .= $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $item_output .= "</li>";
        $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $output .= "\n";
    }
}
```

Cheers and happy coding!